# How to implement Interface with Entity Framework 4.0 generated entities

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Hi I am using EF to generate the classes at the BLL.
Within my classes i have 2 classes named A & B. Both of these classes have common properties so i want to extract the interface named ICommon from them.

My question is ,
Once I take out my interface ICOmmon & how do my EF generated enties implement it?

e.g

```
interface ICommon
{
    int OpenCount{get;set}
}

partial class A: ICommon
{
     how do I implement OpenCount property now?

}
```

Comment: Your current code already works. There's no need to explicitly implement the interfaces.

Comment: Apparently, A and B both have a property `OpenCount`, so they already implement the interface.